# Yii2 ArrayHelper::map() shows <optgroup> with unknown origin

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I used the ArrayHelper for a dropdown list, as it follows. But the dropdown list shows an  for both 'hotel_id' and 'room_type', I do not know where from. Any ideas about that ?

Model File Rules:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['hotel_id', 'room_type', 'max_persons'], 'required'],
            [['hotel_id', 'max_persons'], 'integer'],
            [['room_type'], 'string', 'max' => 28],
        ];
    }
```

Form View File:

```
<div class="rooms-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'hotel_id')->dropDownList([
        ArrayHelper::map(Hotels::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'room_type')->dropDownList([
        ArrayHelper::map(ValidRoomTypes::find()->all(), 'name', 'name')
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'max_persons')->textInput() ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

[image: Inputting hotel id through its name value in the form]
   [image: Inputting room type through its name value in the form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the [] around the ArrayHelper

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'hotel_id')->dropDownList(
    ArrayHelper::map(Hotels::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')
) ?>
```